# What is the best way to create a Python object when you have the class implementaion stored in a string?

Tags: python

What is the best way to dynamically create a Python object instance when all you have is the Python class saved as a string?

For background, I am working in the Google Application Engine environment and I want to be able to load classes dynamically from a string version of the class.

```
problem = “1,2,3,4,5”

solvertext1 = “””class solver:
  def solve(self, problemstring):
   return len(problemstring) “””

solvertext2 = “””class solver:
  def solve(self, problemstring):
   return problemstring[0] “””

solver = #The solution code here (solvertext1)
answer = solver.solve(problem) #answer should equal 9

solver = #The solution code here (solvertext2) 
answer = solver.solve(problem) # answer should equal 1
```

Comment: these are some weird quotes you are using

Comment: Why not simply import the classes from a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alas, `exec` is your only choice, but at least do it right to avert disaster: pass an explicit dictionary (with an `in` clause, of course)!  E.g.:

```
>>> class X(object): pass
... 
>>> x=X()
>>> exec 'a=23' in vars(x)
>>> x.a
23
```

this way you KNOW the `exec` won't pollute general namespaces, and whatever classes are being defined are going to be available as attributes of `x`. *Almost* makes `exec` bearable...!-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [the exec statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) to define your class and then instantiate it:

```
exec solvertext1
s = solver()
answer = s.solve(problem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
>>> solvertext1 = "def  f(problem):\n\treturn len(problem)\n"

>>> ex_string = solvertext1 + "\nanswer = f(%s)"%('\"Hello World\"')

>>> exec ex_string

>>> answer
11
```