# In Python in Google App Engine, how do you capture output produced by the print statement?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working in the Google Application Engine environment where I am loading doctests and python code from strings to test Python homework assignments. My basic implementation ([Provided by Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310254/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-python-object-when-you-have-the-class-implementa)) appears to work for all of my problems except for those containing the print statement. Something seems to go wrong when I attempt to execute the print command within GAE.

How would you modify this example to capture anything written out by the print statement?

```
#This and most other code works
class X(object): pass

x=X()
exec 'a=23' in vars(x)


#This throws an error. 
class X(object): pass

x=X()
exec 'print 23' in vars(x)
```

Comment: ... use the logging module instead, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Hooked has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112396/in-python-in-google-app-engine-how-do-you-capture-output-produced-by-the-print-s/2112456#2112456), but I think you'd be better off storing the value of `sys.stdout` before you modify it and restoring *that* value afterwards rather than restoring `sys.__stdout__` because (I think) the App Engine runtime tinkers with `sys.stdout` in its own way.

That leaves you with something like

```
import StringIO
import sys

# Store App Engine's modified stdout so we can restore it later
gae_stdout = sys.stdout

# Redirect stdout to a StringIO object
new_stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = new_stdout

# Run your code here, however you're doing that

# Get whatever was printed to stdout using the `print` statement (if necessary)
printed = new_stdout.getvalue()

# Restore App Engine's original stdout
sys.stdout = gae_stdout
```

Answer (score 4):

For this problem I like to capture the string output directly. Inside your function I would use something like:

```
import StringIO, sys

# create file-like string to capture output
codeOut = StringIO.StringIO()

# capture output and errors
sys.stdout = codeOut
err = ''

try   : 
    exec code in code_namespace
except Exception:
    err = str(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

And finish with:
`# restore stdout and stderr

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`

To restore normal the function of print.