# Difference between .py and .app script on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

According to [Google App Engine doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers), the script handler can call three types of Python scripts to handle the request match by the URL pattern.

> A script: directive can contain either a file path ending in .py
>   (meaning that the script uses CGI), or a Python module path, with
>   package names separated by dots (meaning that the script uses WSGI).
>   The last component of a script: directive using a Python module path
>   is the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be
>   a WSGI app, and is usually called app by convention.

What is the difference between these three types and their use cases?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no `.app` script file. This is not a valid extension name. Instead, it is a variable inside a script.

## Example

You may see in a `app.yaml` file something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: application.app
```

In this case, the '.app' part is a variable inside application.py, and you can see a piece of code like this inside the `application.py`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPageHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> A `script:` directive can contain either a **file** path ending in `.py` (meaning that the script uses CGI), or a **Python module** path, with package names separated by dots (meaning that the script uses WSGI). The last component of a `script:` directive using a **Python module** path is the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be a WSGI app, and is usually called `app` by convention.
>
> **Note**: just like for a Python `import` statement, each subdirectory that is a package must contain a file named `__init__.py`.

There are actually only two methods of referencing the Python script. First, a **file** path, e.g., `/home/tsr/myscript.py`. Second, a **Python module** path, e.g., `mypackage.mymodule`.

See [Python's documentation on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The .app is the WSGI use - the typical/most common one.

The .py is the CGI use - rare, apparently with issues, see [Does Google App Engine actually implement "normal" CGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295153/does-google-app-engine-actually-implement-normal-cgi)